# Grails plugin which one is good closure-compiler or uglify-js-minified-resources

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am using uglify-js-minified-resources plugin to minify the files. But it always minify the files before serving means files minify per request. Is there any setting for it that it minify the files on application startup. Also want to know if closure-compiler is good enought for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [YUI War Minify](http://grails.org/plugin/yui-war-minify) plugin will minify resources at War creation time. This should do what you are looking for.